# Change edge color, when clicking node in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I want to change the color of the edge which connected a node(nodeA->nodeB and nodeB->nodeC) to red color, when clicking nodeC as in sample.png, by cytoscape.js. Please help me.

`cy.on("tap", "node", (evt) => {evt.cyTarget.connectedEdges().animate({
    style: {lineColor: "red"}`
  })
})`

When I use this code, it changed the colors of all edges that connected to the clicked node.
[image: sample.png]

Comment: So you want the edges, which go into C to be colored red, but not the edges going out of c?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that edges which go into C to be colored red.

Comment: Ok so in your example, just the B -> C edge would be red?

Comment: Sorry, if i am wrong something because I use cytoscape.js first time.I want to red A->B->C

Comment: No problem, I understand now, please review my answer and see if it helps you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cytoscape.js provides some neat functions to filter nodes:

- [incomers()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.incomers) gets edges (and their sources) coming into the nodes in the collection
- [predecessors()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.predecessors) recursively gets edges (and their sources) coming into the nodes in the collection (i.e. the incomers, the incomers' incomers, ...)
- [edges()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.$) gets edges in the graph matching the specified selector

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "100px",
        shape: "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "Top",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "yes",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "no",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Third",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Fourth",
          faveColor: "#56a9f7"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "no"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "no",
          target: "Third"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Third",
          target: "Fourth"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));

cy.unbind('click');
cy.bind('click', 'node', function(node) {
  console.log(node.target.predecessors().edges());
  node.target.predecessors().edges().animate({
    style: {
      lineColor: "red"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```